# change width of InfoWindow in google maps php api

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

i'm using Google Maps PHP API, i'm need to change the width of the "infoWindow" that popup then i click on Markers, i tried a few ways do to that but i'm failed.
i'm using some api that i download from the internet, i'm using the function $MAP_OBJECT->addMarkerByCoords().

```
function getCreateMarkerJS() {
    $_output = "
       function createMarker(map, point, title, html, icon, icon_shadow, sidebar_id, openers){
            var marker_options = {
                position: point,
                map: map,
                title: title};  
            if(icon!=''){marker_options.icon = icon;}
            if(icon_shadow!=''){marker_options.shadow = icon_shadow;}

            //create marker
            var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker(marker_options);
            if(html!=''){
                ".(($this->info_window)?"




                google.maps.event.addListener(new_marker, '".$this->window_trigger."', function() {
                    infowindow.close(); 
                    infowindow.setContent(html);
                    infowindow.open(map,new_marker);
                });

                if(openers != ''&&!isEmpty(openers)){
                   for(var i in openers){
                     var opener = document.getElementById(openers[i]);
                     opener.on".$this->window_trigger." = function() { 

                        infowindow.close();
                        infowindow.setContent(html);
                        infowindow.open(map,new_marker); 

                        return false;                           
                     };
                   }
                }
                ":"")."
                if(sidebar_id != ''){
                    var sidebar = document.getElementById(sidebar_id);
                    if(sidebar!=null && sidebar!=undefined && title!=null && title!=''){
                        var newlink = document.createElement('a');
                        ".(($this->info_window)?"
                        newlink.onclick=function(){infowindow.open(map,new_marker); return false};
                        ":"
                        newlink.onclick=function(){map.setCenter(point); return false};
                        ")."
                        newlink.innerHTML = title;
                        sidebar.appendChild(newlink);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new_marker;  
        }
    ";
    return $_output;
}
```

Comment: Might be useful if you include details on what you have tried and the errors you received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The InfoWindow object has a method `setOptions({opts})` which allows you to change the [InfoWindowOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions). You can use this to set the maxWidth of the InfoWindow.

The actual width of the InfoWinodow is determined by the width of the content, changing the content's width will alter than InfoWindow.